# Having Trouble with string::find

Tags: c++, string, find

I'm writing a C++ program to parse pieces out of web logs, and one of the pieces I want is the requested page. I'm using `string::find` to define the beginning and end of the page, then using `string::substr` to extract it. Here is an example line:

```
172.138.80.174 - - [05/Aug/2001:21:06:27 -0300] "GET /~csc226 HTTP/1.0" 301 303 "http://www.goto.com/d/search/?Keywords=stringVar+%2B+savitch&view=2+80+0&did=" "Mozilla/4.61 [en] (Win98; I)"
```

The requested page is the part right after the `GET`, and the end is right before the `HTTP` is, So I do something like :

```
int beginning = log_entry.find("\"GET") + 5;
int end = log_entry.find("HTTP) - 5;
std::string requested_page = log_entry.substr(beginning, end);
```

This is then what would be contained within `requested_page`:

```
/~csc226 HTTP/1.0" 301 303 "http://www.goto.com/d/search/
```

Instead of

```
/~csc226
```

As you can see, the beginning is correct, but the end is not. I have a log of 3000 lines with the same syntax as the example entry above, and the beginnings of the requested pages in all of them are correct and the ends are not.

Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store the result of `find` in an `int`.  use `std::string::size_type` aka `std::size_t`.

To test if it failed, then compare against `std::string::npos`.

Second, never ever manipulate the result of `std::string::find` until you both confirm it is not `npos` and know that the manipulation moves it within the valid range.  `+5` and `-5` blindly is a no-go.  I don't care if you "know" what your data is.  Don't write buffer overflow culpable code.

Finally, `substr( start, LENGTH )` not `substr( start, end )`.

`std::string` was imported from a different source library than the standard containers.  So its conventions are very different (and often worse).

Comment: Okay, I should have read the documentation beforehand. Thanks for the clear and concise explanation, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
172.138.80.174 - - [05/Aug/2001:21:06:27 -0300] "GET /~csc226 HTTP/1.0" 301 303 "http://www.goto.com/d/search/?Keywords=stringVar+%2B+savitch&view=2+80+0&did=" "Mozilla/4.61 [en] (Win98; I)"
```

So:
`log_entry.find("\"GET") + 5;` will match: `"GET` and then move the iterator 5 places forward to the location:

```
172.138.80.174 - - [05/Aug/2001:21:06:27 -0300] "GET /~csc226 HTTP/1.0" 301 303 "http://www.goto.com/d/search/?Keywords=stringVar+%2B+savitch&view=2+80+0&did=" "Mozilla/4.61 [en] (Win98; I)"
                                                     ^
```

Next `log_entry.find("HTTP"); will match HTTP:

```
172.138.80.174 - - [05/Aug/2001:21:06:27 -0300] "GET /~csc226 HTTP/1.0" 301 303 "http://www.goto.com/d/search/?Keywords=stringVar+%2B+savitch&view=2+80+0&did=" "Mozilla/4.61 [en] (Win98; I)"
                                                              ^
```

You want to use (`size_t length = log_entry.find("\"HTTP") - log_entry.find("\"GET") - 5;`). Finally you need to use std::string::substr correctly [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/).